# CSV Helper:Bad Data Exception

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, csvhelper

Im using only one CSV file to read data to execute my c# automation code. I get CSV Helper:Bad Data Exception issue only while reading certain values.

my strIdentifier Type variable value is returned as null, whereas it need to take as Xpath.

The code, the way of pointing to csv file all remain the same.

Visual version - 2019

Comment: Make the property a string and turn it into an XPath yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var streamReader = new StringReader("Id,Note\n1,<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        
        var nav = records[0].Note.CreateNavigator();
        
        var body = nav.SelectSingleNode("/note/body").Value.Dump();
    }   
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Note).Convert(args => new XPathDocument(new StringReader(args.Row.GetField("Note"))));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public XPathDocument Note { get; set; }
}
```